# Using $view = $_GET['view'] to check for print view

Tags: php, get

I am working within an existing homegrown PHP CMS. There is a 'Print' button which is supposed to allow users to view a printer-friendly page with no header or footer, just the page content. Right now though, it just loads an empty page.

I'm picking up some unfinished code to make this happen, but basically when the user clicks on the print button, the link has the page id with "?view=print" appended to the end. Then, the main content page has an if/else statement that is supposed to check if $view=='print'. If it does, it should then show the page content without the header and footer; if it doesnt', it should load the default page.

There wasn't any actual code to check the view, so I added

```
 $view = $_GET['view'];
```

and then

```
 if ($view=='print') {
     $print = "print";
 }

 if ($print=="print")   { //print view}
 else { //default view}
```

The problem is that I cant load the $content or any other variables into the print layout. I can echo text, so I know the conditional is working, and the $content and other page element variables ($title, $header etc) are loaded into the default view.

So I'm guessing that using GET to check the view variable is making the other page content variables inaccessible. (I've tried POST too).

Is there another way that I can check if it is set to print view? Or another way that I can use GET that will still allow me to access all the other content variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough code to pin point your exact problem. However I can say for sure that accessing one GET variable would not empty out other get or POST variables. This mean that the problem lies elsewhere in your code.

Maybe $view had the page content loaded to it and when you loaded $_GET['view'] in to $view it got wiped away?

try this:

```
if ($_GET['view'] == 'print') {
    // print view
} else {
    // default view
}
```

you can also dump out everything in your $_GET and $_POST so that you can debug.

eg:

```
var_dump($_GET);die;
```

the above code will print to screen all the values in the $_GET super global and stop execution below that line.

Comment: Thanks for your help -- good to know that's not the problem. I'll try the var_dump and keep troubleshooting. Thanks.